# Mockito error : org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have the below code

```
public void testInitializeButtons() {
        model.initializeButtons();
        verify(controller, times(1)).sendMessage(
                eq(new Message(eq(Model.OutgoingMessageTypes.BUTTON_STATUSES_CHANGED),
                        eq(new ButtonStatus(anyBoolean(), eq(false), eq(false), eq(false), eq(false))),
                        anyObject())));
    }
```

which throws the following exception

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
1 matchers expected, 9 recorded.
This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.
    at se.cambiosys.client.medicalrecords.model.MedicalRecordPanelModelTest.testInitializeButtons(MedicalRecordPanelModelTest.java:88)
```

Can someone point to me how to write the test correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do that: eq() can be used only for the mocked method parameters, not inside other objects (like you did in the constructor of `Message`).
I see three options:

- Write a custom matcher
- Use an `ArgumentCaptor`, and test the properties of the Message with asserts()
- Implement `equals()` in the Message class in order to test equality with another Message, based upon the fields you actually want to verify.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot nest matchers like this (although it would be awesome):

```
eq(new Message(eq(Model.OutgoingMessageTypes.BUTTON_STATUSES_CHANGED)
```

When you are using `eq`, the matcher simply uses `equals()` to compare what was passed to mock and what you are providing in `verify()`. That being said you should either implement your `equals()` method to compare only relevant fields or use custom matcher.

As a rule of thumb: you should have the same number of matchers as the number of arguments - or 0.

Answer (score 2):

The value inside sendMessage should just be a regular Message instance, you don't need to use the 'eq' call, similarly inside the ButtonStatus constructor, just use regular objects - you probably want somthing like this:

```
verify(controller, times(1)).sendMessage(
            new Message(Model.OutgoingMessageTypes.BUTTON_STATUSES_CHANGED,
                    new ButtonStatus(false, false, false, false, false),
                    <something else here>);
```

Comment: I want the first parameter to ButtonStatus constructor to be anyBoolean

Comment: Isn't the test deterministic - surely you can tell whether the first value will be true or false? If you really don't know then you would need to write a custom argument matcher: http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.6/javadoc/org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.html

Comment: @codebox_rob: well, often it's not about determinism but about reducing noise. Maybe OP knows what the value should be but he simply doesn't care (in this particular test). +1 for custom argument matcher

Comment: `verify` will [verify argument values](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#argument_matchers) via an `equals` call. So I'd think this solution (providing newly created regular objects) only works if you have also overridden `equals`.

Comment: I don't see how this can possibly work with a `new` operator. A newly created object can never match. The `verify` method requires a "known" value or the use of `any(Message.class)`. Alternately use an `ArgumentCapture` as mentioned in other answers.